# PHP keeps posting the old value from input

Tags: php, mysql

I have a datetime-local that displays an SQL date on first display, and it should be directly changeable to update such value.

```
<input type="datetime-local" onchange="updateDate(this, 'dateEnd', '<?php echo $id;?>')" value="<?php echo $dateEnd; ?>" >
```

This is my script to handle the event

```
function updateDate(element,column,id) {
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to update value?");
        if (result) {
            var value = element.value;     
            $.ajax({
                url:'updateblotters.php',
                type: 'post',
                data:{
                    value: value,
                    column: column,
                    id: id
                },
                success: function(php_result) {
                    console.log(php_result);
                },
                error: function(php_result) {
                    console.log(php_result);
                }
            })
        }                   
}
```

I've been testing it repeatedly in PHP to force a date to be saved into the database, such as

```
  if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $column = $_POST['column'];
    if($column == "dateEnd"){
       $d = strtotime('2020-10-09T11:11:11');
       $value = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $d );           
       var_dump($value);
    }
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE blotters SET $column = :value WHERE blotterId = :id LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    echo ("ABOUT TO BE POSTED".$value);
    $stmt->bindParam(":value", $value);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Yup";
    }
    else {
        echo "fail";
    }
```

But no matter the code, vardump or echo (they do show the value I expected), the Payload will always be the old value from the input, what it first displayed that came from the database, not any of the things I set in PHP, therefore setting no changes to the database.

Comment: Is that date-input inside a `<form>` that you submit afterwards?

Comment: No. The rest of the inputs are type texts and they work pretty well on jquery ajax. I just repurposed the code for the datetime-local input and unfortunately it wasnt that simple as expected

Comment: Please post the query that is being run to change columns

Comment: Added, i kept it pretty simple. The value I expect works up to the echo just before the value is bound. However when I check the payload in debugging, the old value is the thing that was sent.

Comment: Are you certain the query is executed? `column` is a reserved word in MySQL, you might want to add backticks around `$column` in your query

Comment: Yes, it does execute, the if else statement confirms it